# Storing a text file into an array

Tags: android

I need to store a txt file into an array, the txt file is located in res/raw/text.txt

I'm not quite sure as to how the buffered reader and input stream works, I have seen some of the solutions and I'm struggling to use them for my project.

Comment: "I have seen some of the solutions and I'm struggling to use them for my project" -- show what you tried, and show what specific problems you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource("text.txt")
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw, "UTF8"));
List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
while((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
    linesList.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me,

```
InputStream stream = context.getResources().openRawResource("Your file name")
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF8"));
List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
String sentence;

while((sentence = reader.readLine()) != null){
    fileList.add(sentence);
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.